# How to add the content of a file to database?

Tags: java, mysql, file, insert, filereader

I have a text file looks like:

```
    george   19   180     75
    paul     20   182     84
    laura    21   176     73
    ...      ...  ...     ...
```

I want to read this file and add its content to a table with parameters(name, age, height, weight) in my database. The names george, paul, laura should be added to names and etc.
I have written a code like this.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PreparedStatement preparedstatement = null;

    try{
        String read=null;
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patientlist.txt")); 
        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
            name=splited[0];
            age=splited[1];
            height=splited[2];
            weight=splited[3];       
        }
        try {
            addpatient(connection, preparedstatement, name, age, height, weight);   
            if (connection != null)
            try{connection.close();} catch(SQLException ignore){}
            }
        catch (SQLException error) {System.out.println(error);} 
    }

    catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);}        
    }

    public static void addpatient(Connection connection, PreparedStatement preparedstatement, String name, String age2, String height2, String weight2) throws SQLException{
    preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into allpatients(name, age, height, weight) values(?,?,?,?)");
    preparedstatement.setString(1, name);
    preparedstatement.setString(2, age);
    preparedstatement.setString(3, height);
    preparedstatement.setString(4, weight);
    preparedstatement.executeUpdate();

}
```

I think the problem is with my while loop, maybe I have to add a for loop I couldn't manage to do it, I'm not a very good programmer and I appreciate help. Thanks!

Comment: put the  addpatient(connection, preparedstatement, name, age, height, weight);   inside the while loop

Comment: It says "No operations allowed after connection closed." Because when you do that you also take the if statement inside the loop but after the first round connection!= null so it closes

Comment: After all the data updated and then only you close the connection. Otherwise it will be opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
            name=splited[0];
            age=splited[1];
            height=splited[2];
            weight=splited[3];   
            addpatient(connection, preparedstatement, name, age, height, weight);   
         }

if (connection != null)
            try{connection.close();} catch(SQLException ignore){}
            }
```

Place the `addpatient()` inside the while loop then only it will call.

Comment: Ok this works thank you. But now I have another question, lets say from another program I add content to this text file using buffer writer. Every time I run this program, it saves all the data again, how can I just make it save the new data? Thanks

Comment: specify any identification in the file before add content example (date or anything). or delete all the file content before add content in to the file. sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. What you need to do is add the values to preparedstatement in the loop and then execute the statement out side the loop

```
preparedstatement = //Initialize
while(condition){
   preparedstatement.setString(1, name);
   preparedstatement.setString(2, age);
   preparedstatement.setString(3, height);
   preparedstatement.setString(4, weight);
   preparedstatement.addBatch();
}
preparedstatement.executeBatch();
```